# ionic ngClass not working when variable is defined during the render

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a weird issue with Angular in ionic during the render of a template :

```
<div class="subHeader" *ngIf="calendarid === undefined">
    <div *ngFor="let calendar of calendars; let isFirst = first" class="user"
             [ngClass]="{'active': (isFirst) }"
             (tap)="showTheCalendar(calendar.id)">
        <img src="assets/imgs/person.svg" alt="Image">
        <p>{{ calendar.name }}</p>
        <div class="selectMark"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subHeader" *ngIf="calendarid !== undefined">
    <div *ngFor="let calendar of calendars; let isFirst = first" class="user"
              [ngClass]="{'active': calendar.id===calendarid }"
              (tap)="showTheCalendar(calendar.id)">
         <img src="assets/imgs/person.svg" alt="Image">
         <p>{{ calendar.name }}</p>
         <div class="selectMark"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class is correctly applied when `calendarid` is undefined, but at the moment it's defined, the condition is reevaluated in the `*ngIf` but not in the `[ngClass]="{'active': calendar.id===calendarid }"`

I'm begining in Angular and Ionic, so I may not have the reflexes to avoid this issue.

I also thought about this syntax :

```
<div class="subHeader" *ngIf="">
    <div *ngFor="let calendar of calendars; let isFirst = first" class="user"
             [ngClass]="{'active': (isFirst && calendarid === undefined) || (calendarid === calendar.id}"
             (tap)="showTheCalendar(calendar.id)">
        <img src="assets/imgs/person.svg" alt="Image">
        <p>{{ calendar.name }}</p>
        <div class="selectMark"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try with double equal `[ngClass]="{'active': calendar.id==calendarid }`

Comment: Ok it's working, but I don't understant why I would need to do this as they are both number. But for now I don't have the time to look into. Thanks @AbdulRafay !

Comment: mark answer correct if working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `==` (relational operator) if you not sure the type of variables,

use

```
[ngClass]="{ 'active': calendar.id == calendarid }"
```

instead of

```
[ngClass]="{ 'active': calendar.id===calendarid }"
```